# Deserializing a file with arraylist content only shows that 1 element exists

Tags: java

So I load the file in the start of the program, and add any values to it then save it. when I load again, only the first element is shown to exist(size() returns 1)
Why does it not show new added elements?

```
String name;
String desig;
String age;
static ArrayList<Person> personarray = new ArrayList<Person>();

private void SaveButton(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

        Person newperson = new Person();
        name = jTextField1.getText();
        age = jTextField2.getText();
        desig = jTextField3.getText();


        newperson.saveData(name, age, desig);
        personarray.add(newperson);

        try{
           FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(System.getProperty("user.dir") +"/info.dat", true);
           ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOut);
           out.writeObject(personarray);
           out.close();
           fileOut.close();
           System.out.print("done");
        }
        catch(IOException i) {
         i.printStackTrace();
      }
    }


    private void LoadButton(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        ArrayList<Person> retrievedList = null;
        try {
         FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream(System.getProperty("user.dir") +"/info.dat");
         ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(fileIn);
         retrievedList = (ArrayList<Person>) in.readObject();
         in.close();
         fileIn.close();
      }catch(IOException i) {
         i.printStackTrace();
         return;
      }catch(ClassNotFoundException c) {
         System.out.println("class not found");
         c.printStackTrace();
         return;
      }
        Person temp = null;
        for(int i = 0; i < retrievedList.size(); i++ ){
            temp = retrievedList.get(i);

            jTable1.getModel().setValueAt(temp.name, i, 0);
            jTable1.getModel().setValueAt(temp.age, i, 1);
            jTable1.getModel().setValueAt(temp.desig, i, 2);
        }
    public static void main(String args[]) {
       personarray = getSavedList(); // gets the file similar to LoadButton
       System.out.print(personarray.size());
        try {

          File file = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") +"/info.dat");

          if (file.createNewFile()){
            System.out.println("File is created!");
          }else{
            System.out.println("File already exists.");
          }

        } catch (IOException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Please indent your code, don't post what is irrelevant (LoadButton, and all the AWT stuff), and post what is definitely relevant (getSavedList). Create a minimal, complete example (no need for AWT stuff) reproducing the problem, properly indented.

Comment: I apologize for the indentation, It appeared fine before I posted it. The getSavedList() is a copy paste of LoadButton() which just returns the retrievedList variable, so I thought it would be better to post minimal code. So thats why LoadButton is relevant. I apologize for any errors as Im new to Java. And this is the entire working code.

Comment: If you want help, just do what I asked you to do. It's awaste of time to try fixing a problem without being able to reproduce it, or even to see the actual code that causes the problem. Especially when the complete code needed to cause the problem could be posted in 30 lines of code or so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the problem is that you are appending to the file. You use `new FileOutputStream(System.getProperty("user.dir") +"/info.dat", true)`. The second argument, `true`, causes bytes to be written at the end of the file without overwriting the existing file content. So the old version of the list of persons is still in the beginning of the file, and this is the one you read when you read from the file.

Try putting `false` in there instead.